# Create function to use DatePickerDialog and TimePickerDiaglog to catch user input date time

Tags: android, mysql, dialog, datetimepicker

I am trying to write a function to capture user input `Date` and `time` and store in a string value. I successfully create `DatePickerDialog` but for `TimePickerDialog`. I get the error "can not resolve constructor..." (although using the same code as `DatePickerDialog`. Any help is much appreciate. Thanks

Here is my function code

```
public void showDatePicker(View view) {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        int mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        int mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        final TextView selectDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selectDate);


        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(DateTimePicker.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                // dd.MM.yyyy
                selectDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "." + (monthOfYear + 1) + "." + year);
            }
        }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        datePickerDialog.show();

        TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(DateTimePicker.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(android.widget.TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                selectDate.append(hourOfDay + "." +minute);
            }
        },mHour,mMinute);
        timePickerDialog.show();
}
```

And One more question is how to convert string $selectDate to Timestamp and store to remote MySQL database?

Comment: You are missing one parameter for timepicker.

Comment: thanks a lot, can help me figure out what is the missing one? I compare with Date and can not see any difference

Comment: post `TimePickerDialog` class

Comment: can u explain in more detail? what is going wrong for my TimePickerDialog?

Comment: I'm using the default TimePickerDialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [Timepicker dialog documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TimePickerDialog.html):

**Public Constructors**

```
TimePickerDialog(Context context, TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener listener, int hourOfDay, int minute, boolean is24HourView)
```

Creates a new time picker dialog.

```
TimePickerDialog(Context context, int themeResId, TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener listener, int hourOfDay, int minute, boolean is24HourView)
```

Creates a new time picker dialog with the specified theme.

So, please follow this and you need another parameter of type boolean to your `TimePickerDialog` object creation.

e.g,

```
TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(DateTimePicker.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(android.widget.TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                selectDate.append(hourOfDay + "." +minute);
            }
        },mHour,mMinute,false);
```

Comment: thanks a lot your solution work. One more question. How can we reformat the date time receive from user input to send and store to MySQL database through PhP server? I want to store the input date time into a MySQL database

Comment: I'm looking for a Timestamp conversion as MySQL data is a timestamp: for  ex: 2015-11-24 09:52:19.000000. I want to take input from user and store to the MySQL database

Comment: @LêKhánhVinh So you will pass this as a string right?

Comment: My thought is to store string datetime value store from user input. Send to php server. Php then will decode and store value as timestamp to MySQL.

Comment: So, which format you want to send to the php server?

Comment: This is the timestamp receive from php server https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=B7CA716AA8CDDEDF!18497&authkey=!AK4KSuhd0hln1wA&v=3&ithint=photo%2cjpg. I want to reverse the process send user input datetime to php server and store to MySQL database

Comment: Here you can concate all the date, time which you are getting and make a single string and pass it to the server. Here you just need to remember the format in which you are sending, and there parse it according to the format in which you are sending.

Comment: I not familiar with the PhP function to decode string send from android. I use volley to send and object to Php. how to decode it this is my php code https://docs.google.com/document/d/16APWQippnSNr0_BWqDQd36kzRA6IpbsLSHKIt0xgEFY/edit. and my volley request from android. how to store to SQL as time stamp

Comment: @LêKhánhVinh let me check.